# Game: Keyboard Input Simultaneously (Run & Jump)

Tags: jquery, input, keycode, simultaneous

I'm trying to create a jquery powered platformer, but I'm a novice at most. The first issue I've run into is simultaneous keyboard input (run and jump so to speak). Just wondering what I'm doing wrong;

```
var tickRate = 100,
    slideB = 0,
    slideC = 0,
    oldV = 0,
    time = 0;

$('body').keydown(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.keyCode == '38') { jump(); }
    if (e.keyCode == '40') { }
    if (e.keyCode == '37') { slideB += 1; run(); }
    if (e.keyCode == '39') { slideB -= 1; run(); }
    $("#Background").css('left', (slideB * 10) + 'px');
    $("#Tell").html(slideB);
});

var run = function() {
    slideC -= 1;
    if (slideC < -20) {slideC = 0;}
    $("#Sprite").html(slideC * -11);
};

var jump = function(){
    $("#Character").animate({ top: "50px" },{ duration: 1000, easing: "easeOutQuad" });
    $("#Character").animate({ top: "200px" },{ duration: 1000, easing: "easeInQuad" });
}
```

Currently, if I have Run pressed down (right arrow), then I jump (up arrow), I stop running, until I press Run again.

I am going to need an up-counter at some point, so maybe I could tie in a 'check if key is pressed' script.

Any suggestions are helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the general idea, you could try something like this:
**{you should set interval duration depending of each animation duration and/or maybe use `.stop()` method for each animation and/or use flag}**

http://jsfiddle.net/7juFk/

```
(function () {
    $('body').on('keydown keyup', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var key = e.which,
            type = e.type;
        switch (key) {
            case 38:
                [type == 'keydown' ? jump() : clearInterval(intervalJump)];
                break;
            case 37:
                [type == 'keydown' ? run() : clearInterval(intervalRun)];
                break;
        }
    });
    var intervalRun,
    intervalJump,
    run = function () {
        console.log('running');
        clearInterval(intervalRun);
        intervalRun = setInterval(run, 0);
    },
    jump = function () {
        console.log('jumping');
        clearInterval(intervalJump);
        intervalJump = setInterval(jump, 0);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. My draw functions should have been together, with a setInterval to redraw it all.